# How to ignore files locally without adding it in .gitignore

Tags: git, github

I have a `github` repository, which I checked out locally.

- I changed my environment variables in `environment.local-dev.ts` file. (It usually points to localhost, but as I don't have local api repository installed, I updated file to point to my colleagues local api)
- Now, the changed configuration is specific to my need. So, I don't want to commit these changes to the Github repository

I searched for two options :

- To add file in `.gitignore`. But the problem is, I will still see `.gitignore`, which I might commit accidently.
- To add it in `.git/info/exclude`. I did this, but I am still seeing the changed files when I do `git status`

The Github repository, I am working on is already created by someone else. So cannot change the initial configuration.
Also other people are working on the same repository so cannot commit changes which might affter other people negatively.

So, the problem is to find a way to `not commit` files which are being `tracked by git`. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: If the file is already tracked by Git, adding its name to `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` doesn't have any effect. Git consults these files only when it adds to the repository files that it doesn't already track. You also have to `git rm --cached` the file you want to untrack and then commit.

Comment: Be careful, with `git rm` (after push) you will remove the file also from github and probably this is not what you want!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - preventing a particular commit from ever being pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484019/git-preventing-a-particular-commit-from-ever-being-pushed)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. My problem is very different. As my files are already being tracked by git and available in github.

Comment: @axiac - `git rm --cached` as pointed out by Francesco, will remove it from github repsository also. I dont want this. I have a temporary change in my local due to my `local backend` not working properly. For time being I want to use `local ip ` of my colleague but I don't want to do any changes in the github repo.

Comment: Either you want to track the file or you want to ignore it. There is no other option. In fact, you have a different problem. You committed configuration files and this is a common mistake. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38999817/4265352) on a similar question; it tells you how to correctly store the configuration files in a VCS.

Comment: Yes I know what I want to do is not conventional. I searched about it and couldn't find the answer, therefore I asked the question. It's a common problem which I think people must face. The repository is already created by someone else. I don't have control what has been committed. Now the problem is if I want to change configuration for my system but don't want to commit it so that other contributors don't get affected. I know the answer of this question might be "Sorry Cannot do this". But I needed to ask to know if that's the case or not.

Answer (score 12):

**EDIT**: as pointed by @Philippe [`skip-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) would be more appropriate than `assume-unchanged`. In this answer, everything is the same but you just switch the option.

`.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` are only to exclude untracked files.

To ignore local modifications of tracked files, you can use [`git update-index --assume-unchanged FILES...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit).
But there is a risk to forget modifications that need to be committed in the file.
To get the modification visible again: `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged FILES...`.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git update-index --assume-unchanged file

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git ls-files -v
h file

$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file

$ git ls-files -v
H file

$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

You can define some aliases:

```
[alias]
    forget = update-index --assume-unchanged
    unforget = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
    forgotten = ! git ls-files -v | grep ^[a-z]
```

---

A better way would be to have an local ignored configuration overwritting file.

Comment: I don't think this works for files which are already committed in the git repository.

Comment: I tried this but the I am still seeing the files, when I do `git status`. That means I think the files are being tracked after changing the values.

Comment: @Philippe thanks for the info, always used `assume-unchanged`, but `skip-worktree` seems to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree environment.local-dev.ts
```

For further reading, see [git update-index documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) and other related questions, like [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525).

Comment: This works but you could loose changes,  e.g. with `git reset`

Comment: I tried this but I am still seeing the changes in my `git status`. I will go through the article to understand how it is working. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Philippe! I updated the answer with correct command.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what said other answers, that not the `assume-unchanged` feature (that is reserved for big files that is costly to check) that you should use but `skip-worktree`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372